# Автоматическое нажатие на кнопку "Установить расширение"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

При клике на кнопку установки расширения для google chrome из магазина расширений, появляется диалоговое окно с подтверждением установки. Я так предполагаю что это окно confirm js, подскажите есть ли возможность обойти это подтверждение установки? Чтоб по клику на кнопку "Установить" сразу установилось расширение. Заранее спасибо[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Надеюсь что нет и не будет никогда

Comment: Спасибо за ваш комментарий)